# How to display and update logged in users information in an EJS page from Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, ejs

I'm building a page called MyAccount.ejs that displays and updates users (or donors from table donors) information.
The tags that are used in the ejs are input tags with type text with empty values.
The fields are full name, email, phone number, two dropdown lists, blood type and city, etc.

Simplified EJS Code:

```
<form action="MyAccount.ejs" method="post">
 <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" value="" required>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value=""required>
      </div>
 <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">Blood Type</label>
        <select class="form-select " required>
          <option selected hidden style="display:none" value=""></option>
        </select>
      </div>
<button class="btn update-btn fw-bold" type="submit" style="width: 200px;"  name="edit">Update</button> 
</div>
```

Node MyAccount GET Route:

```
    app.get('/MyAccount.ejs', (req, res) => {
  
  const userId = req.session.userId;
  if (!userId) {
    return res.redirect('/login'); // Redirect to login if the user is not logged in
  }
  db.query('SELECT * FROM donors WHERE id = $1', [userId], (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching user data:', err);
      return res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }

    const user = result.rows[0];
    res.render('myaccount', { user });
  });
  
});
```

Node MyAccount POST Route:

```
    app.post('/MyAccount.ejs', (req, res) => {
  // Check if user is logged in
  if (req.session.loggedIn) {
    // Update user data
    // ...
    res.send('Data updated successfully!');
  } else {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
  }
});
```

I'm having problems with how to update the fields from the node js code, and i'm having a problem with the data of logged in donors not being displayed.